# VB.net Moq Public Shared Function

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, tdd, moq

I'm doing test in one vb.net project using Moq framework.

The situation I have now is I want to test one function that have inside it one call to a 'Public Shared Function' from another class and I like to moq this call.
The situation is similar to

```
'Sub in Main Class
Public Sub StartProcess()
    Dim total As Integer = CommonData.GetTotal()
    ...
End Sub

'Function in CommonData class
Public Shared Function GetTotal()
    ...
    Dim total As Integer = database.GetTotal()
    ...
    Return total
End Sub
```

The thing is I can moq the database call to get data that I want because is not a shared object
But what I like to do is moq CommonData.GetTotal to avoid all the internal execution
Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't mock a shared function directly with Moq (you'll have to use a framework like Typemock Isolator or Microsoft Fakes that can actually mock shared functions).

However, you can hide your calls to shared code behind an interface and mock the implementation of that interface.

```
Interface ICommonData
    Function GetTotal() As Integer
End Interface

Public Sub StartProcess(commonData As ICommonData)
    Dim total As Integer = commonData.GetTotal()
    ...
End Sub

Public Class RealCommonData
    Implements ICommonData

     ...calls your shared function...
End Class
```

So you would use `RealCommonData` in production and a mock of `ICommonData` in unit tests.

---

Or, the other way round:

```
Interface ICommonData
    Function GetTotal() As Integer
End Interface

Public Class RealCommonData
 Implements ICommonData

   Function GetTotal() As Integer Implements...
        Dim total As Integer = database.GetTotal()
        ...
        Return total
  End Function
End Class

Module CommonData
    Shared _commonData As ICommonData

    Public Shared Function GetTotal()
        Return _commonData.GetTotal()
    End Function
End Module
```

So, in production you would set `CommonData._commonData` to an instance of `RealCommonData`, and to a mock in unit tests.

This way, you could keep your calls to `CommonData.GetTotal()` just like before without changing this part of the code (I heard some people call this something like Static Gateway Pattern or something similar).

Comment: Thanks Dominic, this is what I think, I prefer to not use this interface because I use this class all across the application and it is simple to access without instantiation.

Maybe I could change to a singleton pattern to have a mix of both approaches.

Thanks

Comment: You could of course go the other way round: put the code of the shared function inside a non-shared class/function that implements an interface, and let your shared function just work on that interface (and store the instance you'll work on in  a shared field). Then you could leave the code that uses the shared function as it is.